# CSV data spreadsheet import has unexpected CR\LF

Tags: libreoffice, csv

The screenshot shows that an unexpected CR\LF break in the first line of CSV data (see red arrow).  I did not expect "Direct" (boxed in red) to show up on line 3 of the spreadsheet.

The top of the screenshot demonstrates no CR\LF before "Direct" when the data is opened in the LibreOffice Writer.

Attempts to exercise the controls in the Text Import UI did not resolve the problem.  Suggestions to explain and return "Direct" to line 2 of the spreadsheet is appreciated.

[image]

[image: Right half of data-import fields:]

UPDATE:  I believe the culprit has been found.  There is rogue ^M: that is appended to the data:

[image]

For some reason, opening the LO-Writer does not suffer from the unexpected CR\LF.  On the other data cut-and-paste from LO-Writer to [Pastebin suffers the CR\LF issue.](http://pastebin.com/4cEGK0ff)   The data has 18 fields:

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the first lines of the csv data source completely? You screenshot seems like the first line of the data is cropped at the right.

Comment: Added screen shot of import UI to show remainder of columns.
 
Line1 ends in 24: - -,JFK,OTBD,American Airlines (AA),American Airlines,6687,13:52,,,,,777 ,,,"Direct",3797,2241,2

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there's a difference between the count of header fields in line 1 and the count of data fields in line 2 to 2+n.

Your screenshot doesn't show the complete csv source, so i can't tell for sure. But it looks like you have 14 or 15 header fields, but at least 18 data fields. So, LO assumes your data table has 14 or 15 columns, and will try to allocate 18 data items there, which works only by putting three (or more) data fields in a new row.

Thus, the solution is to adjust either the header fields or the data fields, so their count is the same.